# See previous revisions of posts

Tags: feature-request, revisions-list, posts

I would like to see each historical status of a post. Without the difference. Just look at what a post looked like before, and that the user can choose the version in time and display it.

Comment: You can already link to a specific revision of a post, e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/705754/1

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thanks, I hadn't seen the Link button, not that it's very explicit to see the post in that historical state to see a link that says Link. You could put that as an answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This feature already exists. The revision list contains a link to each revision:

[image: list of links in a revision, one of them is "Link" which leads to this specific revision]

which will give a direct link to how the post looked like in a certain revision, e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/705754/1

Comment: Note that those links aren't necessarily what was actually displayed for the revision (even disregarding that all revision pages use the now-current CSS, rather than what would have been the CSS at the time of the revision). The Markdown is stored, but the HTML for those revision links is generated now using the Markdown renderer that's in use in the site's backend at the time the page is requested. Currently, that's the CommonMark renderer. This will probably be most visible for revisions where headings didn't have a space after a `#`, but other things like blockquotes are also affected.

Comment: An example is [this answer](//movies.stackexchange.com/a/27014) ([2016-11-28 question page archive](//web.archive.org/web/20161128131426/https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/27012/why-wasnt-interstellar-shot-in-3d)), showing [this revision](//movies.stackexchange.com/revisions/27014/8). Note the revisions page's vertical spaces in the multi-line quote blocks, because the revisions page uses the ComonMark renderer, while the question page uses the HTML rendered in 2014, which is stored for the most recent revision for use on some pages, including question pages, but not revisions pages.