# Can i.stack.imgur.com/[ID].gif, i.stack.imgur.com/[ID].jpg and i.stack.imgur.com/[ID].png be different images?

Tags: support, images, imgur

I believe that i.stack.imgur.com supports only 3 extensions: `.gif`, `.jpg` and `.png`.

Assume these three URLs with the same `[ID]`:

1. `i.stack.imgur.com/[ID].gif`
2. `i.stack.imgur.com/[ID].jpg`
3. `i.stack.imgur.com/[ID].png`

Can they be different images? Or do these 3 URLs always point to the same image?

Comment: This is a feature of Imgur actually, it has nothing to do with SE.

Comment: @Mast Thanks, I didn't know, I'm ok if the question is moved to https://webapps.stackexchange.com then.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At least with some brief experimentation, the answer seems to be **no**.

Using this image (arbitrarily picked from [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/395705)), we can use any of the three format extensions in the image URL to retrieve the same image:

| PNG | JPG | GIF |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image: PNG image] | [image: JPG image] | [image: GIF image] |

Attempting to download any of the three, at least in my browser (Chrome v120), always results in a PNG image (which appears to be the "real" format), regardless of the extension in the URL.

This seems consistent with the idea that the Imgur image IDs are extension-agnostic, and correlate to a specific image outright, rather than a certain image in a specific format.